# change background color on onlclick

Tags: html, css, button, background-color

I have these two buttons. I am wanting to change the background color from `#3A1D13` to `#4C291A` when selected and then back to `#3A1D13` once not selected.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<input type='button' id='hideshow' class='background' value='About'>
<input type='button' id='hideshowcontact' class='background' value='Contact'>
```

Comment: The background colour of what? Do you have any code?

Comment: @Bogieman I believe background color of the buttons :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is tagged Jquery, but you don't need JavaScript at all. You can achieve your result by using the CSS `active` psuedo-class:

If your CSS is defined as follows:

```
.background {
    background-color: #3A1D13;
}
```

Then, all you have to do is this:

```
.background:active {
    background-color: #4C291A;
}
```

However, that applies the color change for the active state to be global to all elements that have the `background` class. Alternatively, you could have done so by applying the `active` psuedo-class on the particular element:

Example, the **about** button:

```
#hideshow:active {
    background-color: #4C291A;
}
```

Note, it's a bit difficult to notice since your colors are visually similar. See this for a working version:

http://jsfiddle.net/eWNLq/1/

Answer (score 1):

You mean in hover?

```
.div button:hover {
background-color: your color here
}
```